# JQuery $(document).on("click") on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I've made some research already online but I can't find any solution to my problem:

I've a web app which is using JQuery and bootstrap, on desktop is working as intended but when I try it on mobile (on Android I've tried Chrome an Brave) but it doesn't work on a single tap on the button but to trigger it need to long press until animation is finished

Here the front-end part and JQuery code:

```js
$(document).on("click ", "#triggerCena", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#dettaglioCena').slideToggle("fast", function() {
        delay = 0;
        $('#dettaglioCena .cibo').each(function() {
            if (!$(this).hasClass('animate__animated animate__bounceInLeft')) {
                delay += 0.02;
                $(this).css("animation-delay", delay + "s");
                $(this).addClass('animate__animated animate__bounceInLeft');
                $(this).css("visibility", "visible");
            }

        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row animate__animated animate__zoomInDown" style="margin:0px;margin-top:15px;margin-bottom:15px;animation-delay:1s;">
    <div class="col-2">
        <img class="mx-auto d-block rounded" width="62" height="50" src="images/pictures/img_community/cena.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="col-7">
        <h1 style="color:white;margin-left:15px;font-size:20px;">Cena</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1">
    </div>
    <div class="col-1" style="margin-right:10px;">
        <i class="fa fa-plus addMeal" style="color:white;font-size:20px;" data-toggle="modal" value="3" data-target="#modalAlimenti"></i>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row bg-light-grey animate__animated animate__zoomInDown" style="margin:0px;margin-bottom:0px;animation-delay:1s;">
    <div class="col-1">
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
        <i style="color:black;">4 Voci</i>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
    </div>
    <div class="col-1">
        <a class="fa fa-angle-down" style="color:black;" id="triggerCena" role="button"></a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="collapse" id="dettaglioCena" style="display: none;">
    <div class="row bg-light-grey" id="175" style="margin:0px;"></div>
    <div class="row bg-light-grey cibo animate__animated animate__bounceInLeft" id="176" style="margin: 0px; visibility: visible; animation-delay: 0.02s;">
        <div class="col-4">
            Grano saraceno </div>
        <div class="col-3">
            50 g </div>
        <div class="col-3">
            171 Kcal
        </div>
        <div class="col-2"><i class="fa fa-trash removeMeal" value="176"></i></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row bg-light-grey cibo animate__animated animate__bounceInLeft" id="177" style="margin: 0px; visibility: visible; animation-delay: 0.04s;">
        <div class="col-4">
            Coniglio </div>
        <div class="col-3">
            150 g </div>
        <div class="col-3">
            295 Kcal
        </div>
        <div class="col-2"><i class="fa fa-trash removeMeal" value="177"></i></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row bg-light-grey cibo animate__animated animate__bounceInLeft" id="178" style="margin: 0px; visibility: visible; animation-delay: 0.06s;">
        <div class="col-4">
            Broccoli </div>
        <div class="col-3">
            300 g </div>
        <div class="col-3">
            102 Kcal
        </div>
        <div class="col-2"><i class="fa fa-trash removeMeal" value="178"></i></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row bg-light-grey cibo animate__animated animate__bounceInLeft" id="179" style="margin: 0px; visibility: visible; animation-delay: 0.08s;">
        <div class="col-4">
            Olio di oliva </div>
        <div class="col-3">
            30 ml </div>
        <div class="col-3">
            265 Kcal
        </div>
        <div class="col-2"><i class="fa fa-trash removeMeal" value="179"></i></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm also using [Animate.css](https://animate.style/) to make animations.

I've already tried to add touchstart and touchend but nothing seems to change the behaviour.

Any help is very appreciated

Comment: try adding , `touchend` event

Comment: As I out in my post, I've already tried but didn't help

Answer (score 0):

Every tap comes with a delay, because it might be that someone is not really clicking but it's the start of a swipe, for example. This is why there's a delay and I think that's what you're talking about?

See here: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2013/12/300ms-tap-delay-gone-away

Comment: Well, I have to keep it pressed more then 300ms. The point is that if I keep it pressed the animation start so it slide the div and all the rows start to appear, if I remove my finger from the button before the slide is finished it just come back as I didnt press it

Comment: And changing click to mouseup?

Comment: Same effect, no changes in behaviour